# Where are the warp zones?

Tags: super-mario-bros

In which levels are the Warp Zones located in *Super Mario Bros.* and how do you get to them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Level 1-2:  Warp to World 2, 3, or 4
- Level 4-2: Warp to World 6, 7, or 8
- Level 4-2:  Warp to Word 5 (Yes, there are two on this level)

The following detail came from [this site](http://www.videogamesblogger.com/2010/04/28/super-mario-bros-1-warp-zone-locations-wii-nes.htm).

> Where to find warp zone #1 hidden in
>   level 1-2
>
> You will find the first Warp Zone
>   located at the end of level 1-2. In
>   order to reach it, you will need to
>   ride the previous elevator to the top
>   and then jump onto the brick ceiling.
>   Run all the way to your right and you
>   will find the Warp Zone. Enter the
>   corresponding Pipe to skip to world’s
>   2, 3 or 4.
>
> Where to find warp zone #2 hidden in
>   level 4-2
>
> This level contains two Warp Zones,
>   one to level 5 located at the end of
>   the level, and this Warp Zone that
>   takes you to levels 6, 7 and 8 located
>   in the middle of the level. To find
>   this Warp Zone look for a high
>   three-brick-long platform that is too
>   high for you to reach, located across
>   from the first elevator platform.
>   There are some invisible blocks that
>   you will need to make appear in order
>   to reach the far left block, which
>   contains a vine. You need to hit the
>   invisible blocks from below to create
>   a staircase allowing you to reach the
>   Vine. To do this, make the first two
>   lower blocks on the righter side
>   appear. They will start to create a
>   staircase. Then hop on them and break
>   the two bricks above. If you haven’t
>   already activated the vine, try to do
>   so now, and then make the following
>   invisible blocks appear if you need
>   them to reach the vine. Climb the vine
>   and you’ll reach the Warp Zone that
>   can take you to worlds 6, 7 or 8
>   depending on which pipe you enter.
>
> Where to find warp zone #3 hidden in
>   level 4-2
>
> To reach the final Warp Zone (note
>   that you can only take one Warp Zone
>   since both are on the same level), you
>   will need to reach the ceiling from an
>   elevator platform and then run all the
>   way across it to the right, just like
>   you did in level 1-2. This Warp Zone
>   will take you to World 5.